# What would be the Objective-C equivalent of this java command:

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

```
data.date = new Date(jObjectTip.getLong("createdAt") * 1000);
```

That command is used to grab data from FourSquare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `createdAt` is unix timestamp, the code will be:

```
NSTimeInterval createdAt = ...;
NSDate *resultDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:createdAt];
```

Note that `NSTimeInterval` is a typedef for `double`, and it stores the time in seconds, unlike Java, so there's no need to multiply the value by 1000;

Answer (score 1):

Uh...not sure what the "createAt" * 1000 means. 1000 times the current date and time?

In Objective C you can use:

- (id)initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(NSTimeInterval)seconds

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html

to create a date time object with an offset:

```
// creates a date time that is 1000 seconds away from the current time
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1000];
```

Comment: I got the point :) the other answer is clearer. So +1 for you still :D